# JetPack Compose disable BottomSheet outside touch

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am using [Accompanist's BottomSheetNavigator](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-material/) to display a BottomSheet in a Compose Application. The requirement is to disable the touch event outside the Bottom Sheet & only perform action on a Button click event. There are no methods like `setCancelable(false)` or `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)` used in non-Compose applications. 
Eg.
In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnb5U.png) image, action should only be taken if user clicks on "**Apply Now**" button, no action should take place if users clicks on device back button or if user touches outside the Bottomsheet. Is there any way I can achieve the said functionality?

Answer (score 35):

Using a `ModalBottomSheetLayout` you can specify the `sheetState` parameter.
In the `ModalBottomSheetState` there is the parameter **`confirmStateChange`**.

> Optional callback invoked to confirm or veto a pending state change.

You can use something like:

```
val state = rememberModalBottomSheetState(
    initialValue= ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden, 
    confirmStateChange = {false})
```

In this way you can touch outside the Bottomsheet without closing it.
In your Apply Now button just use:

```
onClick = { scope.launch { state.hide() } }
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer.

Comment: Nice solution. It took lots of time for me until I found your answer. This should be accepted answer

Comment: confirmStateChange is deprecated now you should use confirmValueChange

Comment: this causes unexpected behaviour

Comment: but if your sheet has contents where you need to scroll then the bottom sheet closes automatically